# discord.js bot restarting for no clear reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

for the past several weeks, my bot has been restarting for no reason what-so-ever. there is nothing in the logs stating any sort of error, the shards just keep restarting and it hits the 1000 login limit every 3-5 hours. what am I doing wrong?

sharding code incase:

```js
const {ShardingManager, Shard} = require("discord.js");
const botsettings = require('./botsettings.json');
const manager = new ShardingManager("./bot.js", {
    token: botsettings.token,
    totalShards: "auto",
});

manager.on('shardCreate', shard => {
    console.log(`[${new Date().toString().split(" ", 5).join(" ")}] Launched shard #${shard.id}`);
})
    manager.on('ready', () => {
        console.log('Shard ready').catch(console.error);
    })
    manager.on('disconnect', (a, b) => {
        console.log('Shard disconnected').catch(console.error);
        console.log(a)
        console.log(b)
    })
    manager.on('reconnecting', (a, b) => {
        console.log('Shard reconnecting').catch(console.error);
        console.log(a)
        console.log(b)
    })
    manager.on('death', (a, b) => {
        console.log('shard died').catch(console.error);
        console.log(a)
        console.log(b)
    
})

manager.spawn(this.totalShards, 5500, -1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used two different modules for sharding and client. Don't do that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with my bot, it's started when i was starting using Intents on my bot. It said on other script like Client.js in **node_modules/src/client/Client.js** do i just put // before the error to just skip the error and now its just keep restart with no error in the console.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30371388)